# Install ipa over link

Tags: ios, flutter, over-the-air

I have a Flutter App and want to make a website to install the `.ipa` for the latest build on their iPhone. I have a `manifest. plist` file with all the information like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/something/my-app.ipa?rlkey=some-key&dl=1</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>$ident</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>$title</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and a link to my website:

```html
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://my-app.vercel.app/1.0.0/manifest.plist">Install App</a>
```

I want this app to be downloadable by everyone like apps like PandaHelper, AppValley, etc. I delivered my App's archive with AdHoc. The problem is that when I click on the link, I get asked if I want to download my App, but when I click yes I can't open my App after the download is finished. I just got an error that my App couldn't be verified.

Comment: The provisioning profile embedded in the app bundle needs to include the udid of the device that you are trying to install it on. You cannot create an app bundle that is installable by everyone in the world.  AppValley misuses Apple Enterprise signing.

Comment: What could happen to your account when you abuse this feature? How can you do this?

Comment: Once Apple determines that you are not following the terms of the enterprise agreement they will [terminate it, which kills all of the apps distributed under it](https://www.theverge.com/2019/1/30/18203551/apple-facebook-blocked-internal-ios-apps).  You also need to be a large company to even get an Enterprise agreement.  You should plan on distributing your app via the App Store, or TestFlight for testing.